# Getting URL of an XHR request in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a web scraping project for scraping products off a website. I've been doing projects like this for a few months with pretty good success, but this most recent website is giving me some trouble. This is the website I'm scraping: https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/usen/web/home. Here's an example of a product page: https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3248125&library=usen&pcck=P-15-11-08-02-05&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL. I have a program that lets me navigate to each product page and extract a majority of the information using BeautifulSoup.

The place I run into issues is trying to get the product number of all the products under the "Accessories Tab". I tried to use Selenium rather than Beautiful Soup to pull up the page and actually click through the Accessories pages. The website throws a 403 error if you try to update the page by clicking on the page numbers or arrow or change the displayed number of products. The buttons themselves don't have an actual link, the href tag = "#" to take you back to the top of the section after it updates the list. I have found that the request URL in the XHR request when you click on one of those page links would take you to a page that has the product information. From there I can make slight changes to the site= and itemsPerPage= parts of the URL and scrape the information pretty easily.

I am scraping 30,000 of these product pages and each one has a different request URL for the XHR request, but there's no recognizable relationship between the page URL and the request URL. Any ideas on how to get the XHR request URL from each page?

I'm pretty fluent in Selenium and Beautiful soup, but any other web scraping packages are unfamiliar and would warrant a little extra explanation.

EDIT: This shows what happens when I try to use Selenium to navigate through the pages. The product list doesn't change, and it gives that error. [Selenium Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZUU.png)
This shows the XHR request that I've found. I just need a way to retrieve that URL to give to Beautiful Soup. [XHR Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lscr.png)

Comment: Best is to use selenium in these cases

Comment: @bigbounty question has been edited to show the error I get when I try to use Selenium.

Comment: The error in the image is not a selenium related error, instead yielded by the server with status code `403`. It often means your request resource have been forbidden, often the result of making a ton of requests to the server. A word of advice: please also be concise with your question and exactly what you want to achieve and avoid any unnecessary details. Long text-based questions doesn't attract the attention of a lot of people.